# How to print data in template django of a diffrent table joined by foreign key?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hello Everyone i have Two model first one is as following:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    bargainprice = models.FloatField(default=0)
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
```

and i am getting this model data using the following view:

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "product.html"
```

and in product.html i am accessing Item objects like this:

```
    <span class="mr-1">
          <del>₹ {{ object.price }}</del>
        </span>
        <span>₹ {{ object.discount_price }}</span>

        {% else %}
        <span> ₹ <span id="pp">{{ object.price }}</span></span>
```

and so on..

**everything working fine up here.** but problem arises when i created the following model:

```
class BargainModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    itemId = models.IntegerField()
    bprice = models.FloatField()
```

i joined this with foreign key as mentioned.
**what i want to do is print the " bprice " in the product.html of the same user but i am not able to do it **
can anyone help me with this i am new to Django.
Thanks in advance

Comment: your itemId field should be a ForeignKey to Item instead of an Integer field. That way you can join in the template

Answer (score 0):

in this case you need to import User like

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class BargainModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    itemId = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bprice = models.FloatField()
```

in product.html you can call the model of BargainModel it also contains the Item with user

Comment: how to t pass this model data to view and access in template?

Comment: i dont what actually you want to display data.
normally you can pass as you pass above
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = ChangeModel
    template_name = "product.html"

Answer (score 0):

It is better to work with a `ForeignKey` since this will guarantee referential integrity. You thus shoudl define the `BargainModel` as:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Bargain(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        Item,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    bprice = models.FloatField()
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['item', 'user'], name='unique_user_item')
        ]
```

In the `DetailView`, we can then look if there is a `Bargain` record for the given item and user with:

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "product.html"

    def get_bargain(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Bargain.objects.filter(item=self.object, user=request.user).first()
```

Then you can render this with:

```
{{ view.get_bargain.bprice }}
```

if there is a related `Bargain`, then it will show the corresponding `bprice`.

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Model` suffix. Therefore it might be better to rename <s>`BargainModel`</s> to `Bargain`.

Comment: thanks sir for beautiful and clear explaination. but there is an issue in the get_bargain function it says "request is not defined"

Comment: @aashishsethi: I made a typo, it is `self.request`, not `request`.

Comment: I am doing all the stuff the same but not getting anything on the template by {{ view.get_bargain.bprice }} do I need to replace "view"  with "ItemDetailView"?

Comment: @aashishsethi: no,in that case it means there is no `Bargain` model that has a record for the given logged in user and the item it is rendering... You thus need to populate that model in order to get bargain information.

Comment: i have a record in the bargain value with all correct values like "Bargain object (3)" with user, item and bprice but i am unable to get the daata to the template is there any issue with the query??

Comment: @Bargain: what are the `.item_id` and `.user_id` of that record? What do you get when you print `print(self.object.pk)` and `print(self.user.pk)`?

Comment: i get nothing in console "  def get_bargain(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            print("this is the user ", self.user.pk)
            return Bargain.objects.filter(item=self.object, user=request.user).first()

Comment: @aashishsethi: you do use `{{ view.get_bargain.bprice }}`, right? so `view`, not `ItemDetailView`?

Comment: i am using {{ view.get_bargain.bprice }} but i am not getting anything

Comment: @aashishsethi: are you sure the user is logged in? What if you `print` before the `if request.user...` check?